# Auto-Upload to one drive dosent contain screenshots or saved photos

Tags: lumia, onedrive, photos, camera

After enabling the auto-upload feature, it works fine that every new photo i take is uploaded, yet any screenshots or saved photos i save from within apps etc don't seem to be uploaded automatically unless i do it.

Is this a glitch, or is there another way to set it automatically?

I'm running windows phone 8.1 on Lumia Denim update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, only the pictures you take will be uploaded to OneDrive.

You can suggest improvements at http://windowsphone.uservoice.com